# Any good Point of Sales apps/plugins/gems that integrate with Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Can someone recommend a good Point of Sales app that plays nice with Spree?

Basically, it should be able to allow in-store purchases processed by a checkout clerk. Ideally, it would have barcode scanning, receipt printing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [opensource rails apps](http://www.opensourcerails.com/)